# link html bookmark from one page to another page

Tags: html, notepad++, bookmarks

This is my first time making a website and I can't seem to get my bookmark link "upcoming events" to work in my other page. It only works in the home page. Here is the code in my home page:

```
<nav>
    <b>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="rides.html">Rides</a>
    <a href="info.html">Info</a>
    <a href="order.html">Order</a>
    <a href="#UpcomingEvents">Upcoming Events</a>
    <a href="#RelatedNews">Related News</a>
    </b>
</nav>
<hr>

<h2>About Us</h2>
<p>Fun is always in season at Busch Gardens ® Williamsburg in Virginia. From thrilling coasters and kid-friendly attractions to world-class dining and shows, there’s something for the whole family.<br>
Busch Gardens is one of the my favorite amusment parks because of their setup. It's wonderful to be in the 'Germany' part of the park in one moment and then the "Roman" part the next! </p>
<hr>

<h3 id="UpcomingEvents">Upcoming Events</h3>
<p>Das Festhaus: March 31<br>
Britmania: June 30<br>
Summer Nights: July 1 - August 31<br>
Howl-O-Scream: September 23 - October 29</p>
<hr>

<h4 id="RelatedNews">Related Park News</h4>
<!-- include your links here -->
<p><a href="https://seaworldparks.com/en/buschgardens-williamsburg/food-and-wine">Food and Wine Festival</a></p>
<p><a href="https://seaworldparks.com/en/buschgardens-williamsburg/kidsiderate?from=HomeCollection">Kidsiderate</a></p>

<p><a href="https://seaworldparks.com/en/buschgardens-williamsburg/christmastown?from=BGWhome">Christmas Town</a></p>
```

And this is the code for my order page:

```
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="rides.html">Rides</a>
    <a href="info.html">Info</a>
    <a href="order.html">Order</a>
    <a href="html_UpcomingEvents.html#UpcomingEvents">Upcoming Events</a>
    <a href="html_Related News.html#Related News">Related News</a>

<hr>
<h2>Order Information</h2>
<p>Our online ordering page is down currently. Please check back later in a few weeks.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: On which html file is the `#UpcomingEvents` id located?

Comment: You need to make sure file `html_UpcomingEvents.html` do exist and in the same folder of your `my order page`. Also make sure `id="UpcomingEvents"` exists in `html_UpcomingEvents.html`.

Comment: If it's true as you say that it works in your home page, then change the link on the not-working html to: `index.html#UpcomingEvents`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, the link on the non-working html should be changed to:

```
<a href="index.html#UpcomingEvents">Upcoming Events</a>
```